# How to change the path of Chrome app shortcut

Tags: google-chrome

I don't want to create new shortcut with tools > create application shortcut.

The problem is that I moved my files to another location, and now I want several chrome apps icons to redirect to those locations.

is there a solution or it must be done manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change it in the target of your shortcut.

Just click on your shortcut right click > properties > you choose shortcut tab.

In the shortcut tab you will see target field and there you can change the specific target, and place the real path of your targeted file.

After the path of your chrome installation, there goes an app location:
-app=file:///C:/Program%20Files/... (or whatever the path is) - so change it.